# Does the effective skill of a "casting item" give an energy discount as caster skill would?

Tags: magic-items, spellcasting, gurps-4e

I'm playing in a campaign that's (mostly) running under *DFRPG* (4th Ed. rules exist as legacy, since as a play-by-post it's been running for many years and predates much of *DF* and all of *DFRPG*).

I've just built a character who uses a magic item to cast a spell he can also cast himself (main reasons for this are: no skill penalty for "spells on" and the value of the enchantment allows it to also act as a Power Item).  Given that the minimum skill to enchant is 15 with both Enchant and the spell applied (even though Enchantment is strictly an NPC activity in DF/DFRPG), the casting skill for the item must be 15 or higher -- but I haven't found a specific statement whether a user-powered item-cast spell gives the same energy discount as if the spell had been cast directly at skill 15 or higher.

Is this explicit somewhere (in *DF/DFRPG* or *Magic* 4th) that I haven't found?

Comment: Related: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/208516/does-an-item-cast-but-user-powered-spell-count-as-a-spell-on-for-effective-ca

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, an item-cast spell's skill level does not give a discount on the energy cost.

This is clear in both DFRPG ***Exploits***, p. 77 and ***GURPS Magic***, p. 19. You have to read slightly carefully, because of the term "Power" which is used as effective skill for items that cast spells.

- Exploits: "Energy cost is the same as for a normal casting of the spell.
  High Power doesn’t affect this ..."
- Magic: "Energy cost is the same as for a normal casting of the spell. High Power does not affect this (but the Power spell does – see p. 57).

Comment: So the only direct advantage of having an item that lets me cast a spell I know at SL 15 is to avoid the footprint?  Guess that's another question...